# how to call a function on load of an element?

Tags: javascript, dom, onload

I am trying to call a function onload of elements so that I can specify different changes of each elements I am calling the function.

like i have many divs and each and every div has same data-attribure, I am calling all divs with same data-attribute. Each and every div has different html text, I want to call them, when I am loading the page and get those different values. Like in jQuery we call 'each' function. Here I am submitting my html and javascript code... that will draw a clear picture of it.

```
   <-- html -->
   <div data-attribute="one">
        <span class='value'>1000</span>
   </div>
   <div data-attribute="two">
        <span class='value'>420</span>
   </div>
   <div data-attribute="three">
        <span class='value'>2000</span>
   </div>

   <!---- javascript ---->
    var abc = document.querySelectorAll('[data-attribute]'); 
        for (i= 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
            abc[i].onload = function(){  
            // --------- working well with click / mousemove events -----
               console.log('function called!');
            };
        }
```

I don't want to use any library or don't want to call the function on element.

P.S. also let me know if there is other option to do the same.
Thank you..

Comment: Your elements are static so they must load before you can execute your javascript otherwise javascript will not be able to find the element to check the load state... For this I think you will need to create the elements once the page has loaded, then you should be able to use `onload` or a `load` event listener depending on what sort of elements you're loading. I'm finding it hard to understand your question so this is the best I can offer at this moment in time.

Comment: As @NewToJS hints, you have a "chicken and egg" problem. You cant assign an event handler until an element has loaded. What are you actually trying to achieve inside this `onload` handler? It may be that you can perform an action when the *whole page* has loaded, and vary the behaviour depending on some other attribute of the elements.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes , I  want to perform an action when the whole page has loaded, and vary the behaviour depending on some other attribute of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

You could wait for the entire DOM to load, and perform any actions you require.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var abc = document.querySelectorAll('[data-attribute]');
    for (i= 0; i < abc.length; i++) {
         var elem = abc[0];
         if(elem.getAttribute("data-attribute") == "one"){
             // do something here
         }
    }
}
```

You can expand this idea for as many different attributes/elements as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Ready and Load are executed upon document object model. So, you cannot call them on a specific element. In this case, you can use set-timeout function after the DOM is ready to change on multiple elements.

Comment: Actually, this answer is right. I've tried all of 'DOMContentLoaded', 'load' and 'ready', and doesn't work. I found this answer, and tried with `setTimeout()` function and it works well.